# Cover the OS task bar using JavaFX

Tags: javafx, fullscreen, taskbar

I have google-jitsued the living daylights out of this one and I can't find an answer.

How can I use JavaFX to cover the task bar in the OS? (All OS but the requirement is a Windows system).

I am currently looking at a Delphi system that is able to do this and I mean, really, Delphi is simple as anything. If it can do it, Java has to be able to have the potential to do this.

I am writing the system using JavaFX so please don't give me swing solutions :) The client has requested FX especially.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your main stage in [full screen mode](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/stage/Stage.html#setFullScreen%28boolean%29).

```
stage.setFullScreen(true)
```